# implicitly wait issue in switching frame or window

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I got one finding that if we use

`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`

it works fine when to find and element, can take  minimum 0 second to maximum 40 seconds. but in case of switching window or frame it takes total maximum 40 seconds , means it acts as `Thread.sleep(40000)`.

Has anyone faced same? please share it.

Thanks,
Iqbal

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue in selenium 2.53 at places. Specially in IE, moving back to 2.53 fixed it for me. Try it!